# Granting only board access in Azure DevOps

Tags: tfs, azure-devops

Is there any way to grant only board access to Azure DevOps (TFS) users without showing Repo's (codes)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. In the `Project Settings`-`Permissions`, click `New Group` and create a new group, add the users you want to "grant only board access to Azure DevOps".

[image]

Then, in this group's `Permissions`, set all the permissions to "deny" accept those in the `Boards`( these you can set to "Allow").

[image]

> without showing Repo's (codes)?

As for this requirement, you need to go to the `Project Settings`-`Repos`-`Repositories`, select the target groups or users, set the "Read" permission to "Deny". After this, the group members or users can not see the repo file anymore.

[image]

Comment: Great, the Azure DevOps versions are different. For the part one there is no menu named "Board", so I marked `Deny` whole the permissions for the created group. The second part is OK. I accepted as answered.

Comment: Does not work if the user is not logged in